# Display slide progress percentage in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to display the slide progress percentage on each slide, along the slide number.

In my current power-point template I have the following data to display slide progress in a text box

SlideNumber of TotalNumberofSlides

The TotalNumberofSlides is manually entered in the Slide Master, as I have many slides in backup which are kept after the 'Thank You' slide. What I require is a percentage which will be basically SlideNumber / TotalNumberofSlides %

So, it will look something like this:

15 of 100 (15%)

Comment: You could fairly easily write something like this in VBA to add text shapes with the necessary text to each slide (after first deleting any previously added text so as not to totally clutter the slide up).  You'd fire the VBA manually whenever you changed the number of slides in the pressie or just before saving.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I have no knowledge of Powerpoint VBA, it would be helpful if you could provide the code and tell how to work with it

Comment: That's not how it works.  Stackoverflow offers help with code when there's a problem.  It's not a place to come and get code written for you for free.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks Steve for explaining how Stackoverflow works. I might have read wrong about this site, looking at the thousand of other posts on Stackoverflow, where experts don't necessarily write "codes for free", but guide others with examples and links which might be probable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

even if not the "real answer", you might want to rethink if percentage is a good idea (as it's only the number of slides, not the amount of time taken for them).
I suggest using a Progress Indicator instead. This enables your viewers to easily see what has been talked about and what is still comming up.

I extended the progress dots from Edgar Loper quite a bit. Please check out the **free** - and **open source** (you can look at the code there) - version of my/a **PowerPoint Progress Indicator** at the following link.

The ZIP includes a PPT add in which adds a new ribbon to PowerPoint and **works on Windows and MAC, Office 2010 and up, 32bit and 64bit!**

It lets you create a nice progress bar with extra infomation (if you structure your presentation).

Link to the latest version:

Short URL: http://url.olaf-noehring.de/progressindicator

Full URL: http://www.datenbank-projekt.de/index.php/beispiele/progress-indicator-powerpoint-2010-2013-2016-32-and-64-bit-windows-and-mac-os

(and Adam Wilsons Github page: https://github.com/AdamWilsonLab/progress_indicators )

Olaf